# How can i get populate my elements name from an array in mongoose with objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to show the "name" from the "books" collection  , what i'm trying to do is get "bookId" with req.paramsbookId and show it in the "history" array instead of bookId itself, thanks for any help

Method: `localhost:3000/users/5f0da88156a370091499406f/borrow/5f0cd134fa4ada27787a5d85`

```
exports.borrowBook=asyncHandler(async(req,res,next)=>{
        
   if (req.params.bookId && req.params.id) {
       bookId=req.params._id;
       userId=req.params.id;
       console.log("userid:"+userId);
       const bookName=req.params.bookId;
            
       User.findByIdAndUpdate( userId,{ "$push": { history: {"name":bookName} } },{new:true}).exec();
              }
       res.status(200).json({success:true,msg:'borrow book'});
})
```

Here is my books collections

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0cd134fa4ada27787a5d85"
    },
    "name": "test",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-07-13T21:25:08.261Z"
    },
    "slug": "test",
    "__v": 0
 }
```

This is my users collection

```
{
    "name": "Esin Öner",
    "history": [{
        "name": ["5f0cd134fa4ada27787a5d85"],
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f0daa930643d71380071627"
        }
    }, {
        "name": ["5f0cd134fa4ada27787a5d85"],
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f0dbca1c0402b1aa472b218"
        }
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want. You want to, given an element in your "book" collection, push it into "users" collections as a new element in "history" object. Is that right?

Comment: i want to save the book collection's name "test" in the users collection's history array right now it shows books id instead of it's name

Comment: Follow @dhruv-shah answer. Basically, your URL only contains IDs, but you need to query your DB to obtain the book with that ID

Answer (score 1):

For inserting the book name instead of book id in the history array of users document, you would require to first find the book on the basis of the `bookId`.

And then use the `findOneAndUpdate` method to update the `history` array of the user's document.

Also, there is an issue with your implementation of `findOneAndUpdate` method. The first argument of `findOneAndUpdate` method is an `object` instead of a parameter [(reference)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html).

You need to make the following changes to get the desired outcome:

```
exports.borrowBook=asyncHandler(async(req,res,next)=>{
   
   try {
       if (req.params.bookId && req.params.id) {
           bookId=req.params._id;
           userId=req.params.id;
           console.log("userid:"+userId);
           const bookName=req.params.bookId;

           const bookRecord = await Books.find({"_id": bookId});
       
           await User.findByIdAndUpdate( {"_id": userId},{ "$push": { history: {"name":bookRecord.name} } },{new:true}).exec();
       }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.status(400).send(e);
    }
    
    res.status(200).json({success:true,msg:'borrow book'});
})
```